# Better way to use various versions of custom View in XML layout in different API levels?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml, android-custom-view

For example I have two versions of my custom `View` called `MyView` (for API 4-10) and `MyView_v11` (for API 11+). They both inherit from the `View` class in Android. `MyView_v11` simply extends `MyView` and overrides one method of `View` which is *only available in API 11+*.

Currently I'm using different layout files like:

```
layout
    main_activity.xml
layout-v11
    main_activity.xml
```

The first layout defines a view which points to `MyView`, the second one *only* changes that view and points it to `MyView_v11`.

*My question*: How can I use *only one* file like `layout/main_activity.xml` *with* some separate helper layout files for different API levels? Because in the layout there are lots of other views, but only one custom view. I want to use the same technique as the one that Andoid SDK uses to generate `R.style.AppTheme` when you create new sample Android project:

```
values:
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme" />
values-v11:
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo" />
```

---

*Edited*: I'd prefer other solutions over `commonsware`. I hope this is right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could always put `MyView` in its own separate layout, and use `include` to reference it in your `main_activity.xml`. Then you would just need two API specific versions of your simple `my_view_layout.xml` layout and only one `main_activity.xml`. This would allow you to copy as little xml as possible.

```
 layout
     main_activity.xml
     my_view_layout.xml
 layout-v11
     my_view_layout.xml
```

http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts.html

Comment: Thank you. I'm sorry for my words.